# n-tuples definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Kuratowski's definition of n-tuples:

$$(a,b,c,d) = \left\{ {\{ a\} ,\{ a,b\} ,\{ a,b,c\} ,\{ a,b,c,d\} } \right\}$$

This means:
$$(a,b,c) = \left\{ {\{ a\} ,\{ a,b\} ,\{ a,b,c\} } \right\}$$
Also,
$$(a,b,b,c) = \left\{ {\{ a\} ,\{ a,b\} ,\{ a,b,b\} ,\{ a,b,b,c\} } \right\} = \left\{ {\{ a\} ,\{ a,b\} ,\{ a,b\} ,\{ a,b,c\} } \right\} = \left\{ {\{ a\} ,\{ a,b\} ,\{ a,b,c\} } \right\}$$
Which implies:
$$(a,b,c) = (a,b,b,c)$$
What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you get this definition?

Comment: Yeah, that definition isn't going to work, because even if you don't care that some $3$-tuples can be equal to some $4$-tuples. For example, you have the real problem that $(a,b,b)=(a,a,b)$.

Comment: I found this in a textbook called "Naive set theory". I don't know if I misunderstood the author's intention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your definition is wrong. In my experience, Kuratowski's definition of $n$-tuples is defined inductively by
$$(a,b) = \{ \{a\}, \{a,b\} \}$$
and, for $n>2$,
$$(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) = (a_1, (a_2, \dots\, a_n))$$
This definition doesn't give rise to any nonsense.

For instance,
$$(a,b,c) = \{ \{a\}, \{a, \underbrace{\{ \{b\}, \{b,c\} \}}_{(b,c)} \} \}$$
whereas
$$(a,b,b,c) = \{ \{a\}, \{a, \underbrace{\{\{b\}, \{b, \underbrace{\{ \{b\}, \{b,c\} \}}_{(b,c)} \} \}}_{(b,b,c)} \} \}$$

Comment: The above aren't "falsehoods," they just have problems for real usage. :)

Comment: I'd say $(1,2,3)=(1,2,2,3)$ is false! Or did I misinterpret your comment?

Comment: It's a definition. It isn't a falsehood, it just indicates that you can't use the definition for what you want it to be. A falsehood is a very particular thing in mathematics, and it is bad to confuse it with "intuitive" meanings. In particular, I'd call that a "problem" with the definition, not a falsehood.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Fair point. Perhaps I meant "should be false"!

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I misunderstood the author's explanation for a definition. Sorry if I bothered anyone with this question. :)

Comment: Great answer. Since we define $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ as $(a_1,(a_2,\ldots,a_n))$, this means $A^n=A \times A^{n-1}$ (where $a_i \in A \forall i=1,\ldots,n$. Although I have also seen $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ defined the other way as $((a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}),a_n)$, which says $A^n = A^{n-1} \times A$. Too bad these definitions don't agree with each other. I have posted another question on the issue: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964092/the-empty-tuple-or-0-tuple-its-definition-and-properties